# SecKeyRawVerify and OSError -9809

Tags: ios, objective-c, security-framework

I am using digital certificates to sign data files in my App.  The code fragment below fails when the call to `SecKeyRawVerify` returns with -9809.  This is running on an iPhone.  I can't even identify exactly what this error code means

The prior Security Framework calls to load and create the SecTrustRef from which the public key is obtained seem fine - no errors.  The only slight issue is that the call to `SecTrustEvaluate` returns a `kSecTrustResultUnspecified`, but I assume that is because the policy I am using is the boilerplate one returned by the `SecPolicyCreateBasicX509` call.

Any assistance or insight would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

```
SecKeyRef keyRef = SecTrustCopyPublicKey (trustRef);

fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"data" withExtension:@"txt"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];

fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"data" withExtension:@"sgn"];
NSData *signature = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];

NSLog(@"Hash block size = %zu",SecKeyGetBlockSize(keyRef));

status = SecKeyRawVerify (keyRef,
                          kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA1,
                          (const uint8_t *)[data bytes],
                          (size_t)[data length],
                          (const uint8_t *)[signature bytes],
                          (size_t)[signature length]
                          );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered what's happening.  The `SecKeyRawVerify` call  takes the digest of your data as the input, not the data itself.  The code below works - and incidentally, if the signature is not verified because the underlying data has changed, then the status return is -9809.

Thanks

```
CC_SHA1((const void *)[data bytes], [data length], (unsigned char *)hash);

status = SecKeyRawVerify (keyRef,
                          kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA1,
                          hash,
                          20,
                          (const uint8_t *)[signature bytes],
                          SecKeyGetBlockSize(keyRef)
                          );
```

Comment: It's not that `SecKeyRawVerify` expects the hash of your data. It's that whatever you used to generate the signature in the first place created a signature based on the hash of your data.

Answer (score 3):

That error is defined (along with other related ones) in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecureTransport.h` as `errSSLCrypto`. The comment there calls it "underlying cryptographic error", which is not a particularly descriptive description.

One thought: `kSecTrustResultUnspecified` means that the trust level is equal to the default system policy. Are all the certificates in the chain trusted?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain. The root cert for the chain is self signed and the signing certificate is signed by that root, so the chain itself is good, although at a system level there is no trust in the root. The certs are not loaded into the keychain - the trustRef is created dynamically using the certs loaded from a pkcs12 blob