# Sign on OS X, Verify on iOS and OSStatus -9809

Tags: ios, macos, security, openssl, security-framework

I am using Apple's [Security Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/SecurityFrameworkReference/). I am able to sign and then successfully verify all on OS X, but when I try to use `SecKeyRawVerify` on iOS it fails with -9809 error.

I've played with various PKCS padding options and many other attributes but I'm just not able to get this to verify correctly.

*Note that the code below probably has leaks all over the place, just trying to get this to function properly first.*

**OS X Signing code:**

```
NSData* signData(NSData* plainData, SecKeyRef privateKey) {
    CFErrorRef error;

    /* Create the transform objects */
    SecTransformRef signer = SecSignTransformCreate(privateKey, &error);
    if (error) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }                                    

    /* Explicitly set padding type (necessary?) */
    SecTransformSetAttribute(signer,
                             kSecPaddingKey,
                             kSecPaddingPKCS1Key,
                             &error);
    if (error) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }

    /* Specify digest type */
    SecTransformSetAttribute(signer,
                             kSecDigestTypeAttribute,
                             kSecDigestSHA1,
                             &error);
    if (error) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }

    /* OS X calculates SHA1 hash/signature for us */
    SecTransformSetAttribute(signer,
                             kSecTransformInputAttributeName,
                             plainData,
                             &error);
    if (error) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }

    CFTypeRef signature = SecTransformExecute(signer, &error);
    if (error || !signature) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }

    CFRelease(signer);

    return signature;
}
```

**and iOS verification code:**

```
+ (NSData *)verifyData:(NSData *)data
              usingKey:(SecKeyRef)publicKey {
    size_t signatureByteLength = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);

    if (signatureByteLength > data.length)
    {
        NSLog(@"Signature length is greater that data length.");
        return nil;
    }

    NSData *signature = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, signatureByteLength)];
    NSData *plainData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(signatureByteLength, data.length - signatureByteLength)];

    NSLog(@"signatureLength='%lu', signatureBytes='%@', plainDataLength=%lu", (unsigned long)signature.length, signature, (unsigned long)plainData.length);

    size_t hashByteLength = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH;
    uint8_t* hashBytes = (uint8_t *)malloc(hashByteLength);

    if (CC_SHA1([plainData bytes], (CC_LONG)[plainData length], hashBytes))
    {
       NSData *b = [NSData dataWithBytes:hashBytes length:hashByteLength];
       NSLog(@"hashBytesLength='%lu', hashBytes=%@", (unsigned long)b.length, b);

        OSStatus status = SecKeyRawVerify(publicKey,
                                  kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA1, // I have also tried kSecPaddingPKCS1, doesn't work
                                  hashBytes,
                                  hashByteLength,
                                  (uint8_t *)[signature bytes],
                                  signatureByteLength);

        switch (status)
        {
            case errSecSuccess:
                NSLog(@"SecKeyRawVerify success.");
                return plainData;

            case errSSLCrypto:
               NSLog(@"SecKeyRawVerify failed: underlying cryptographic error");
               break;

            case errSecParam:
               NSLog(@"SecKeyRawVerify failed: one or more parameters passed to a function where not valid.");
               break;

            default:
               NSLog(@"SecKeyRawVerify failed: error code '%d'", (int)status);
               break;
       }
    }
   return nil;
}
```

I created the private and public keys via command line using the following OpenSSL commands:

```
1.    // Generate private and public key pair
openssl genrsa -out rsaPrivate.pem 1024

1a. // Generate public key
openssl rsa -in rsaPrivate.pem -pubout -outform PEM -out rsaPublic.pem

2. //Create a certificate signing request with the private key
openssl req -new -key rsaPrivate.pem -out rsaCertReq.csr

3. //Create a self-signed certificate with the private key and signing request
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in rsaCertReq.csr -signkey rsaPrivate.pem -out rsaCert.crt

4. //Convert the certificate to DER format: the certificate contains the public key
openssl x509 -outform der -in rsaCert.crt -out rsaCert.der
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [SecKeyRawVerify - OSError Unknown (-9809)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10757033).

Comment: @jww I've looked at that post and have tried their solution but it did not solve the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The code I posted is correct, but the padding needs to be set as `kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA1` per the `SecKey.h` header file:

> ```
> If you are verifying a proper PKCS1-style signature, with DER encoding
> of the digest type - and the signedData is a SHA1 digest - use
> kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA1.
> ```

Also, you might want to make sure your public key in `.der` format is the correct one :)

Comment: Oh, good work. I thought `SecKeyRawVerify` did *not* handle any encoding/padding details. I thought it just performed the exponentiation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (CC_SHA1([plainData bytes], (CC_LONG)[plainData length], hashBytes))
{
    NSData *b = [NSData dataWithBytes:hashBytes length:hashByteLength];
    NSLog(@"hashBytesLength='%lu', hashBytes=%@", (unsigned long)b.length, b);
    ...
}
```

It appears you are not encoding and applying the padding correctly. The encoding and padding gets applied before the hashing. See RFC 3447, [Public-Key Cryptography Standards (PKCS) #1: RSA Cryptography Specifications Version 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447) (or the PKCS #1 specification).

Comment: A bit confused by your reply... The `CC_SHA1` method computes the hash, but it's not actually used until I call `SecKeyRawVerify` where all the parameters are passed in and the verification is handled internally. The `SecKeyRawVerify` takes in the hash (digest) as a parameter, along with the rest (pub key, signature, etc.). Since the parameters to that selector take in padding and the hash I believe it should handle all that in the one step.